# hide a twitter-bootstrap tab-pane on small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some tabs on my website. What I want is to hide one of the tabs on smaller screens (phones). when working with classes i just use the `hidden-xs` which works great, but with the `li role="presentation">` I can't get this to work. Im using the latest version of `twitter-bootstrap`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

Just gave the tab an id and then

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    #map-tab {
        display: none;
    }
}
```